# Button push and button release events in Android getting mixed up

Tags: android, android-button

I want to create a button that will send 'W' when pushed and 'X' when released. The way I have it coded now, when I press the button, it does nothing, and when I release it, it sends 'W'. What am I doing wrong? Code:

```
    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("FORWARD");
    but.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    but.setId(Tab2_Forward);
    but.setOnClickListener(this);
    but.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    panelH.addView(but);

    public void onClick(View v) {
       int cmdId = v.getId();
       if (cmdId == Menu_Tab1) {
          startDiscoverBluetoothDevices();
       }
       if (cmdId == Tab2_Forward) {
          if (Bee_btSocket != null)
             try {
                 Bee_btSocket.getOutputStream().write('w');
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
but.setOnTouchListener(btnTouch);


private View.OnTouchListener btnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            System.out.println("Touch");
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            System.out.println("Release");
        return false;   //  the listener has NOT consumed the event, pass it on
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

button.onKeyDown() = does somethings when pressed
and button.onKeyUp() = does something when released
or 
button.onTouch() = does somthing when pressed
button.onClick() = does something when released

```
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        makethisToastup();}});
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        makethisToastdown();
        return false;
    }});

public void makethisToastup(){
Toast.makeText(this, "Buttonup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void makethisToastdown(){
Toast.makeText(this, "Buttondown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: hai Storm2010..thx for ur response..there should i put it?can teach me?